# Python flask-excel gives an empty array , what i am doing wrong?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make an excel file out of this list but it always download an empty excel file although that it has contents and i can view it in my html template, any idea what i am doing wrong?

```
@admin.route('/reports/search')
@login_required
def search_reports():
    reports = Reports.query.whoosh_search(request.args.get('query')).all()

    if request.args.get('x'):
        return excel.make_response_from_array(reports, "xls")

    return render_template('admin/reports/search.html',
                       reports=reports, title='Search')
```

Answer (score 0):

you have given

```
if request.args.get('x'):
    return excel.make_response_from_array(reports, "xls")
```

I read the documentation at  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Excel/0.0.5

i think the "xls" you've given depends, on the data that is returned. 
try using csv if array returns a csv.
not sure but do try read the documentation too

Comment: thanks for your try but i've tried csv it's also not working giving empty file